# Print v. Return Statement

Tags: python

In doing this (https://leetcode.com/problems/rotate-array/) leetcode question I am printing the correct result, but returning an incorrect result.

I must be missing something because I should be printing and returning the same thing.

My stdout (print statement) matches the 'expected' result; however, my output doesn't...

[Compiled Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOSRI.png)

```
class Solution:
    def rotate(self, nums: List[int], k: int) -> None:
        """
        Do not return anything, modify nums in-place instead.
        """
        new_nums = [ ]
        new_index = 0
        old_index = len(nums)-k

        # Fill in the 'beginning' portion of new array
        while(new_index<k):
            new_nums.append(nums[old_index])

            new_index += 1
            old_index += 1

        old_index = 0   # reset 'old_index' accordingly
        # Fill in the 'end' portion of new array
        while(new_index<len(nums)):
            new_nums.append(nums[old_index])

            new_index += 1
            old_index += 1

        print(new_nums)
        return new_nums
```

[image]

Comment: Show your output

Comment: It says: `Do not return anything, modify nums in-place instead.`. You should follow that in order to pass. See [in place algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm) if the terminology is new to you. You could assign each element of `new_nums` to `nums` one by one, but that's against the spirit of the algorithm, so try to do it all without an auxiliary data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Notice this comment at the top of the code: `Do not return anything, modify nums in-place instead.` This clearly indicates your function should not return the values, but should modify the `nums` list that is passed in as the first (non-self) argument.

You will need to use list operations, such as `list.append()`, `list.remove()`, `list.pop()` to achieve the desired goal.

Happy coding!